# SQL SELECT COMMAND WITH JOIN in C#

Tags: c#, sql, select, join, alias

```
CourseRepeater cr = new CourseRepeater();
List<CourseRepeater> course = new List<CourseRepeater>();
string sql = "SELECT u.Name, u.Surname, c.Name, c.ClosingDate, c.BeginDate FROM Course AS c, JOIN Users AS u on u.UserID=c.UserID";
DataTable dt = DataBase.SQLSelect(sql);
if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    cr.Name = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString(); // ?
}
```

I have `Database` class that contains `SQLSelect()`.Here there is not problem.
My question is so : If I want to get `Users.Name`, `dt.Rows[0]["Name"]` in this row ,I should write `dt.Rows[0]["Name"]` or `dt.Rows[0]["u.Name"]` ?

Comment: but I have aslo `Course.Name`.

Comment: How will browser know that I mean  Which of them .

Comment: Well i guess it would be a better practice if you get that `c.Name` as `c.Name AS CourseName`

Comment: You should alias them in the query. Does dt.Rows[0]["u.Name"] actually work? You could use the ordinal position to get the one you want  dt.Rows[0][0], but that fragile. Again aliases as u.Name UsersName, c.Name CourseName is a better bet.

Comment: `"SELECT u.Name AS UserName, u.Surname, c.Name AS CourseName , c.ClosingDate, c.BeginDate FROM Course AS c, JOIN Users AS u on u.UserID=c.UserID"`
So ?

Comment: Yeah that'll do. Now `dt.Rows[0]["UserName"]` is what youre looking for.

Comment: @Jeyhun Yes. That should do it. AS is optional in the alias, so u.Name UserName is the same as u.Name AS UserName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well move the comment to the answer.

You should alias the fields in the query.

The other option are more fragile or not as clear.

```
SELECT u.Name UsersName, c.Name CourseName FROM...
```

Comment: isn't there diffrence between `SELECT u.Name UsersName` and `SELECT u.Name AS UsersName` ?

Comment: Not in SQL Server at least. You didn't specify an RDBMS. SE:ECT UsersName = u.Name would also be equivalent. Try this, for example: SELECT 1 One,2 AS Two, Three = 3